# Laravel Custom Package Route Not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have tried to develop a custom package but ended with errors
[image]

I have a package structure in my below as given below:

[image]

can any body tell me why the package route is not working or i have done some errors?If you can provide me the links for the development of the package in laravel 5.2 then i will be very appreciated.
Please i need help.

composer
[image]

service provider
[image]

Comment: Could you add the content of your `composer.json` and `DemoServiceProvider.php`?

Comment: yes i did what you have asked me

Comment: Have you tried looking at this? https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/packages#routing

Comment: but i am using laravel 5.2?

Answer (score 4):

Same issue on Laravel 5.3 custom package routes will not be working.

First make sure you have registered your service provider in "config/app.php" section "providers".

And second it MUST BE after the Laravel service providers, but before the App service providers.

Comment: This worked for me in Laravel 5.8. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For me on Laravel 5.3, it worked after I put it last in the 'providers' array of config/app.php